# OneDrive Sync Engine has stopped working (with callstack and disassembly)

Tags: crash, onedrive, debug, disassembly

Searching online I can see that some people have this problem but I cannot find any solution. I tried to change onedrive location, run the onedrive troubleshooter (no problems found) and nothing worked. I used the refresh option and it worked again until I downloaded the latest update. I am running windows 8.1 64bits. I was able to get a callstack and disassembly on the moment when onedrive breaks but I cannot make sense of it. Maybe someone with more knowledge can see something meaningfull there?

```
"OneDrive Sync Engine has stopped working"
```

## CALLSTACK

```
>   kernel32.dll!RaiseFailFastException()  Unknown
    SyncEngine.dll!AssertWorker(bool,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,...)  Unknown
    SyncEngine.dll!Expirable::StartExpirationCheck(__int64) Unknown
    SyncEngine.dll!SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel(long,class std::basic_string<unsigned short,struct std::char_traits<unsigned short>,class std::allocator<unsigned short> > const &,__int64)    Unknown
    SyncEngine.dll!CoreLoopWorkItemQueuer::DoWork(bool) Unknown
    SyncEngine.dll!coreLoopWorker(bool &)   Unknown
    SyncEngine.dll!coreLoop(void *) Unknown
    msvcrt.dll!_beginthreadex()    Unknown
    msvcrt.dll!_endthreadex()  Unknown
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown
```

## DISASSEMBLY (SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreateWnsChannel)

```
00007FF8849860BA 40 89 44 24 38       mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],eax  
00007FF8849860BF 48 89 4C 24 30       mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rcx  
00007FF8849860C4 48 8D 05 85 D6 E0 FF lea         rax,[string L"Failed CreateSubscri"... (07FF884793750h)]  
00007FF8849860CB 48 89 44 24 28       mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax  
00007FF8849860D0 4C 8D 0D C9 D9 E0 FF lea         r9,[string L"SyncEngineSubscripti"... (07FF884793AA0h)]  
00007FF8849860D7 48 8D 15 72 CB E0 FF lea         rdx,[string L"shell\\skydrive\\synce"... (07FF884792C50h)]  
00007FF8849860DE 41 B8 50 01 00 00    mov         r8d,150h  
00007FF8849860E4 B9 02 00 00 00       mov         ecx,2  
00007FF8849860E9 C6 44 24 20 00       mov         byte ptr [rsp+20h],0  
00007FF8849860EE E8 FD FD E5 FF       call        _LogError (07FF8847E5EF0h)  
00007FF8849860F3 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF8849860F6 E8 6D 05 00 00       call        SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::Teardown (07FF884986668h)  
00007FF8849860FB 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF8849860FE 48 83 C4 50          add         rsp,50h  
00007FF884986102 5B                   pop         rbx  
00007FF884986103 E9 48 F9 FF FF       jmp         SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::BackOffSubscriptionRetryTime (07FF884985A50h)  
00007FF884986108 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986109 CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498610A CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498610B CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498610C CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498610D CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498610E CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498610F CC                   int         3  
SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::IsConnected:
00007FF884986110 40 53                push        rbx  
00007FF884986112 48 83 EC 20          sub         rsp,20h  
00007FF884986116 48 8B D9             mov         rbx,rcx  
00007FF884986119 E8 D6 F8 FF FF       call        SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::AssertAPIReady (07FF8849859F4h)  
00007FF88498611E 83 BB 94 00 00 00 02 cmp         dword ptr [rbx+94h],2  
00007FF884986125 0F 94 C0             sete        al  
00007FF884986128 48 83 C4 20          add         rsp,20h  
00007FF88498612C 5B                   pop         rbx  
00007FF88498612D C3                   ret  
00007FF88498612E CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498612F CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986130 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986131 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986132 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986133 CC                   int         3  
SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnChannelLost:
00007FF884986134 40 53                push        rbx  
00007FF884986136 48 83 EC 40          sub         rsp,40h  
00007FF88498613A 48 8B D9             mov         rbx,rcx  
00007FF88498613D E8 B2 F8 FF FF       call        SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::AssertAPIReady (07FF8849859F4h)  
00007FF884986142 48 8D 05 B7 D5 E0 FF lea         rax,[string L"OnChannelLost called"... (07FF884793700h)]  
00007FF884986149 48 89 5C 24 30       mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rbx  
00007FF88498614E 48 89 44 24 28       mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax  
00007FF884986153 4C 8D 0D 46 D5 E0 FF lea         r9,[string L"SyncEngineSubscripti"... (07FF8847936A0h)]  
00007FF88498615A 48 8D 15 EF CA E0 FF lea         rdx,[string L"shell\\skydrive\\synce"... (07FF884792C50h)]  
00007FF884986161 41 B8 42 01 00 00    mov         r8d,142h  
00007FF884986167 B9 04 00 00 00       mov         ecx,4  
00007FF88498616C C6 44 24 20 00       mov         byte ptr [rsp+20h],0  
00007FF884986171 E8 7A FD E5 FF       call        _LogError (07FF8847E5EF0h)  
00007FF884986176 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF884986179 48 83 C4 40          add         rsp,40h  
00007FF88498617D 5B                   pop         rbx  
00007FF88498617E E9 E5 04 00 00       jmp         SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::Teardown (07FF884986668h)  
00007FF884986183 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986184 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986185 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986186 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986187 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986188 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986189 CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498618A CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498618B CC                   int         3  
SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel:
00007FF88498618C 48 8B C4             mov         rax,rsp  
00007FF88498618F 55                   push        rbp  
00007FF884986190 56                   push        rsi  
00007FF884986191 57                   push        rdi  
00007FF884986192 48 81 EC 90 00 00 00 sub         rsp,90h  
00007FF884986199 48 C7 40 A8 FE FF FF FF mov         qword ptr [rax-58h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh  
00007FF8849861A1 48 89 58 20          mov         qword ptr [rax+20h],rbx  
00007FF8849861A5 48 8B 05 74 0E 14 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [__security_cookie (07FF884AC7020h)]  
00007FF8849861AC 48 33 C4             xor         rax,rsp  
00007FF8849861AF 48 89 84 24 80 00 00 00 mov         qword ptr [rsp+80h],rax  
00007FF8849861B7 49 8B E9             mov         rbp,r9  
00007FF8849861BA 49 8B F0             mov         rsi,r8  
00007FF8849861BD 8B FA                mov         edi,edx  
00007FF8849861BF 48 8B D9             mov         rbx,rcx  
00007FF8849861C2 49 83 78 18 08       cmp         qword ptr [r8+18h],8  
00007FF8849861C7 72 05                jb          SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel+42h (07FF8849861CEh)  
00007FF8849861C9 49 8B 00             mov         rax,qword ptr [r8]  
00007FF8849861CC EB 03                jmp         SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel+45h (07FF8849861D1h)  
00007FF8849861CE 49 8B C0             mov         rax,r8  
00007FF8849861D1 89 54 24 48          mov         dword ptr [rsp+48h],edx  
00007FF8849861D5 48 89 44 24 40       mov         qword ptr [rsp+40h],rax  
00007FF8849861DA 8B 41 1C             mov         eax,dword ptr [rcx+1Ch]  
00007FF8849861DD 89 44 24 38          mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],eax  
00007FF8849861E1 48 89 4C 24 30       mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rcx  
00007FF8849861E6 48 8D 05 E3 D1 E0 FF lea         rax,[string L"Starting OnCreatedWn"... (07FF8847933D0h)]  
00007FF8849861ED 48 89 44 24 28       mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax  
00007FF8849861F2 C6 44 24 20 00       mov         byte ptr [rsp+20h],0  
00007FF8849861F7 4C 8D 0D 62 D1 E0 FF lea         r9,[string L"SyncEngineSubscripti"... (07FF884793360h)]  
00007FF8849861FE 41 B8 11 01 00 00    mov         r8d,111h  
00007FF884986204 48 8D 15 45 CA E0 FF lea         rdx,[string L"shell\\skydrive\\synce"... (07FF884792C50h)]  
00007FF88498620B B9 04 00 00 00       mov         ecx,4  
00007FF884986210 E8 DB FC E5 FF       call        _LogError (07FF8847E5EF0h)  
00007FF884986215 85 FF                test        edi,edi  
00007FF884986217 0F 88 98 00 00 00    js          SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel+129h (07FF8849862B5h)  
00007FF88498621D 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF884986220 E8 B3 F8 FF FF       call        SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::CheckState (07FF884985AD8h)  
00007FF884986225 8B F8                mov         edi,eax  
00007FF884986227 85 C0                test        eax,eax  
00007FF884986229 0F 88 86 00 00 00    js          SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel+129h (07FF8849862B5h)  
00007FF88498622F C7 83 94 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [rbx+94h],2  
00007FF884986239 48 8D 7B 38          lea         rdi,[rbx+38h]  
00007FF88498623D 49 83 C9 FF          or          r9,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh  
00007FF884986241 45 33 C0             xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF884986244 48 8B D6             mov         rdx,rsi  
00007FF884986247 48 8B CF             mov         rcx,rdi  
00007FF88498624A E8 71 68 E7 FF       call        std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::assign (07FF8847FCAC0h)  
00007FF88498624F 48 89 AB 88 00 00 00 mov         qword ptr [rbx+88h],rbp  
00007FF884986256 48 83 7F 18 08       cmp         qword ptr [rdi+18h],8  
00007FF88498625B 72 03                jb          SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel+0D4h (07FF884986260h)  
00007FF88498625D 48 8B 3F             mov         rdi,qword ptr [rdi]  
00007FF884986260 48 89 7C 24 40       mov         qword ptr [rsp+40h],rdi  
00007FF884986265 8B 43 1C             mov         eax,dword ptr [rbx+1Ch]  
00007FF884986268 89 44 24 38          mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],eax  
00007FF88498626C 48 89 5C 24 30       mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rbx  
00007FF884986271 48 8D 05 08 D2 E0 FF lea         rax,[string L"Captured WNS uri ptr"... (07FF884793480h)]  
00007FF884986278 48 89 44 24 28       mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax  
00007FF88498627D C6 44 24 20 00       mov         byte ptr [rsp+20h],0  
00007FF884986282 4C 8D 0D D7 D0 E0 FF lea         r9,[string L"SyncEngineSubscripti"... (07FF884793360h)]  
00007FF884986289 41 B8 20 01 00 00    mov         r8d,120h  
00007FF88498628F 48 8D 15 BA C9 E0 FF lea         rdx,[string L"shell\\skydrive\\synce"... (07FF884792C50h)]  
00007FF884986296 B9 04 00 00 00       mov         ecx,4  
00007FF88498629B E8 50 FC E5 FF       call        _LogError (07FF8847E5EF0h)  
00007FF8849862A0 48 8B 93 88 00 00 00 mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbx+88h]  
00007FF8849862A7 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF8849862AA E8 01 E1 04 00       call        Expirable::StartExpirationCheck (07FF8849D43B0h)  
00007FF8849862AF 8B F8                mov         edi,eax  
00007FF8849862B1 85 C0                test        eax,eax  
00007FF8849862B3 79 31                jns         SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannel+15Ah (07FF8849862E6h)  
00007FF8849862B5 48 8D 15 9C D1 E0 FF lea         rdx,[string L"OnCreatedWnsChannel" (07FF884793458h)]  
00007FF8849862BC 48 8D 4C 24 58       lea         rcx,[rsp+58h]  
00007FF8849862C1 E8 DE CA E6 FF       call        std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > (07FF8847F2DA4h)  
00007FF8849862C6 90                   nop  
00007FF8849862C7 4C 8D 44 24 58       lea         r8,[rsp+58h]  
00007FF8849862CC 8B D7                mov         edx,edi  
00007FF8849862CE 48 8B CB             mov         rcx,rbx  
00007FF8849862D1 E8 C6 FD FF FF       call        SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::HandleFailureAtStage (07FF88498609Ch)  
00007FF8849862D6 90                   nop  
00007FF8849862D7 45 33 C0             xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FF8849862DA B2 01                mov         dl,1  
00007FF8849862DC 48 8D 4C 24 58       lea         rcx,[rsp+58h]  
00007FF8849862E1 E8 42 77 F0 FF       call        std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_Tidy (07FF88488DA28h)  
00007FF8849862E6 48 8B 8C 24 80 00 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+80h]  
00007FF8849862EE 48 33 CC             xor         rcx,rsp  
00007FF8849862F1 E8 DA 18 E6 FF       call        __security_check_cookie (07FF8847E7BD0h)  
00007FF8849862F6 48 8B 9C 24 C8 00 00 00 mov         rbx,qword ptr [rsp+0C8h]  
00007FF8849862FE 48 81 C4 90 00 00 00 add         rsp,90h  
00007FF884986305 5F                   pop         rdi  
00007FF884986306 5E                   pop         rsi  
00007FF884986307 5D                   pop         rbp  
00007FF884986308 C3                   ret  
00007FF884986309 48 8D 8A 58 00 00 00 lea         rcx,[rdx+58h]  
00007FF884986310 E9 4B 49 F0 FF       jmp         std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::~basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > (07FF88488AC60h)  
00007FF884986315 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986316 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986317 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986318 CC                   int         3  
00007FF884986319 CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498631A CC                   int         3  
00007FF88498631B CC                   int         3  
SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::OnCreatedWnsChannelCallback:
00007FF88498631C 40 53                push        rbx  
00007FF88498631E 55                   push        rbp  
00007FF88498631F 56                   push        rsi  
00007FF884986320 57                   push        rdi  
00007FF884986321 48 81 EC F8 00 00 00 sub         rsp,0F8h  
00007FF884986328 48 C7 44 24 58 FE FF FF FF mov         qword ptr [rsp+58h],0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh  
00007FF884986331 48 8B 05 E8 0C 14 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [__security_cookie (07FF884AC7020h)]  
00007FF884986338 48 33 C4             xor         rax,rsp  
00007FF88498633B 48 89 84 24 E0 00 00 00 mov         qword ptr [rsp+0E0h],rax  
00007FF884986343 49 8B F1             mov         rsi,r9  
00007FF884986346 49 8B D8             mov         rbx,r8  
00007FF884986349 8B FA                mov         edi,edx  
00007FF88498634B 48 8B E9             mov         rbp,rcx  
00007FF88498634E 8B 41 1C             mov         eax,dword ptr [rcx+1Ch]  
00007FF884986351 89 44 24 38          mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],eax  
00007FF884986355 48 89 4C 24 30       mov         qword ptr [rsp+30h],rcx  
00007FF88498635A 48 8D 05 BF D2 E0 FF lea         rax,[string L"OnCreatedWnsChannelC"... (07FF884793620h)]  
00007FF884986361 48 89 44 24 28       mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rax  
00007FF884986366 C6 44 24 20 00       mov         byte ptr [rsp+20h],0  
00007FF88498636B 4C 8D 0D 2E D2 E0 FF lea         r9,[string L"SyncEngineSubscripti"... (07FF8847935A0h)]  
00007FF884986372 41 B8 03 01 00 00    mov         r8d,103h  
00007FF884986378 48 8D 15 D1 C8 E0 FF lea         rdx,[string L"shell\\skydrive\\synce"... (07FF884792C50h)]  
00007FF88498637F B9 04 00 00 00       mov         ecx,4  
00007FF884986384 E8 67 FB E5 FF       call        _LogError (07FF8847E5EF0h)  
00007FF884986389 48 8D 44 24 40       lea         rax,[rsp+40h]  
00007FF88498638E 48 89 44 24 48       mov         qword ptr [rsp+48h],rax  
00007FF884986393 48 8D 44 24 60       lea         rax,[rsp+60h]  
00007FF884986398 48 89 44 24 50       mov         qword ptr [rsp+50h],rax  
00007FF88498639D 48 8B D3             mov         rdx,rbx  
00007FF8849863A0 48 8D 4C 24 60       lea         rcx,[rsp+60h]  
00007FF8849863A5 E8 D2 C2 E7 FF       call        std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > (07FF88480267Ch)  
00007FF8849863AA 90                   nop  
00007FF8849863AB 48 89 74 24 28       mov         qword ptr [rsp+28h],rsi  
00007FF8849863B0 48 89 44 24 20       mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],rax  
00007FF8849863B5 44 8B CF             mov         r9d,edi  
00007FF8849863B8 4C 8B C5             mov         r8,rbp  
00007FF8849863BB 48 8D 8C 24 90 00 00 00 lea         rcx,[rsp+90h]  
00007FF8849863C3 E8 AC EC FF FF       call        std::tr1::bind<void,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel,long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > const & __ptr64,__int64,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel * __ptr64,long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >,__int64> (07FF884985074h)  
00007FF8849863C8 90                   nop  
00007FF8849863C9 48 8B D0             mov         rdx,rax  
00007FF8849863CC 48 8D 4C 24 40       lea         rcx,[rsp+40h]  
00007FF8849863D1 E8 9A EA FF FF       call        CreateWorkItem<std::tr1::_Bind<void,void,std::tr1::_Bind4<std::tr1::_Callable_pmf<void (__cdecl SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::*const)(long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > const & __ptr64,__int64) __ptr64,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel,0>,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel * __ptr64,long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >,__int64> > > (07FF884984E70h)  
00007FF8849863D6 90                   nop  
00007FF8849863D7 48 8B D0             mov         rdx,rax  
00007FF8849863DA 48 8B CD             mov         rcx,rbp  
00007FF8849863DD E8 E2 F4 FF FF       call        SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::AddWorkItem (07FF8849858C4h)  
00007FF8849863E2 90                   nop  
00007FF8849863E3 48 8D 8C 24 90 00 00 00 lea         rcx,[rsp+90h]  
00007FF8849863EB E8 0C F2 FF FF       call        std::tr1::_Bind<void,void,std::tr1::_Bind4<std::tr1::_Callable_pmf<void (__cdecl SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::*const)(long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > const & __ptr64,__int64) __ptr64,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel,0>,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel * __ptr64,long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >,__int64> >::~_Bind<void,void,std::tr1::_Bind4<std::tr1::_Callable_pmf<void (__cdecl SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel::*const)(long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > const & __ptr64,__int64) __ptr64,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel,0>,SyncEngineSubscriptionWnsChannel * __ptr64,long,std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >,__int64> > (07FF8849855FCh)  
00007FF8849863F0 48 8B 8C 24 E0 00 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+0E0h]  
00007FF8849863F8 48 33 CC             xor         rcx,rsp  
00007FF8849863FB E8 D0 17 E6 FF       call        __security_check_cookie (07FF8847E7BD0h)  
00007FF884986400 48 81 C4 F8 00 00 00 add         rsp,0F8h  
00007FF884986407 5F                   pop         rdi  
00007FF884986408 5E                   pop         rsi  
00007FF884986409 5D                   pop         rbp  
00007FF88498640A 5B                   pop         rbx  
00007FF88498640B C3                   ret  
00007FF88498640C 48 8B 8A 50 00 00 00 mov         rcx,qword ptr [rdx+50h]  
00007FF884986413 E9 48 48 F0 FF       jmp         std::basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> >::~basic_string<unsigned short,std::char_traits<unsigned short>,std::allocator<unsigned short> > (07FF88488AC60h)
```

The `SyncEngine.dll!Expirable::StartExpirationCheck` disassembly is [here](http://pastebin.com/v0LeSySU) (SU does not let me write more text)

Comment: hi i have the same problem but i think after updating it my problem solved